# How to remove just a certain kind of annotation on MapKit?

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

In my map I have two kinds of annotations, the custom one and the standard one. I need to update them in my map separately so when I loop through the custom ones I don't want to interfere with the other.

Here's the code where I register the annotations:

```
map.register(customAnnotation.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: "customAnnotation")
map.register(MKPointAnnotation.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: "standardAnnotation")
```

and the delegate method:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }
    let annotation = mapkitView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "customAnnotation") as! customAnnotation
    return annotation
}
```

Here's the function to update the annotation locations:

```
@objc func updateFireMarkersOnMap(){
    print("data count:",fireData.count)
    for annot in mapkitView.annotations {
        if annot.isEqual(customAnnotation.self) {print("custom annotation found")}
        mapkitView.removeAnnotation(annot)
    }

    for data in fireData {
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(data.lat), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(data.long))
        mapkitView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
}
```

In this function I expected it would print "custom annotation found" 350 times (the number of annotations I have on the map). It never prints this line. I tried to use `if annot is customAnnotation`, `annot.iskind()`, `isMember()` but none of these worked. How can I identify which annotation I'm dealing with?

I'm deleting all my annotations and adding them again after I fetch the locations data from an API but I have two sources and I can't mix them up so I need to deal with them separately.

When I update one kind of annotation I can't delete the others.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. Because of your bracket alignment all annotations will be removed all the time, which can be done in a batch statement

```
let annots = mapkitView.annotations
mapkitView.removeAnnotations(annots)
```

But this can work as well.

```
  @objc func updateFireMarkersOnMap(){
        print("data count:",fireData.count)
        for annot in mapkitView.annotations {
            if annot is customAnnotation { print("custom annotation found") }
            mapkitView.removeAnnotation(annot)
        }

        for data in fireData {
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(data.lat), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(data.long))
            mapkitView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }
    }
```